# PL/SQL Extracting difference between dates in different formats

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, extract, date-difference

This is the query I am trying to use:

```
select a.cr_mdt_abstractor_dt, b.created,
(trunc(a.CR_MDT_ABSTRACTOR_DT - b.created) || ' days and ' ||<br>
        to_char(to_date('01/01/2000', 'MM-DD-YYYY') + (a.CR_MDT_ABSTRACTOR_DT - b.created),
                'HH24:MI:SS'
               )
       ) as Diff
from CR_MDT a,
CR_MDT_VERIFY b
where a.CR_MDT_ID=b.FK_CR_MDT_ID
```

The error I am getting is:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

The column b.created is in date format `09-MAR-17 10.52.23.195311 AM(TIMESTAMP)`
and column for a.cr_mdt_abstractor_dt is in DATE.

Can I get help to correct the query so that column b.created is in converted format to extract from a.cr_mdt_abstractor_dt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `TRUNC` on `CR_MDT_ABSTRACTOR_DT` (`TIMESTAMP`) and `created` separately .

```
SELECT a.cr_mdt_abstractor_dt,
  b.created,
  TRUNC(a.CR_MDT_ABSTRACTOR_DT) - TRUNC(b.created)
  || ' days and '
  || TO_CHAR(to_date('01/01/2000', 'MM-DD-YYYY') + (a.CR_MDT_ABSTRACTOR_DT - b.created), 'HH24:MI:SS' ) AS Diff
FROM CR_MDT a,
  CR_MDT_VERIFY b
WHERE a.CR_MDT_ID=b.FK_CR_MDT_ID;
```

Sample output:

```
CREATED       DIFF
07-09-17    -182 days and 12:15:15
```